# WSO2 ESB wsdl endpoint with password

Tags: wso2, esb, endpoint, wso2-esb

How can I define an **endpoint** in **ESB** that connects to a **wsdl** that has basic autentification?

Comment: the backend service endpoint have basic authentication or to see the wsdl using a navigator do you need to provide user/pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible!
Try to restrict the rights to wsdl from ESB, not from wsdl.

Answer (score 3):

You can add following configuration in the synapse config before sending message to endpoint.

```
<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode('username:password'))"  scope="transport"/>
```

If your wsdl url require Basic Authentication you can do is authenticate in the browser download the wsdl and create your service based in downloaded wsdl file.